# How to scrape part of a class that has no sub-attribute attributed to it?

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape the parental rating of IMDB pages but after the class "subtext" the rating seems to not have a attribute.
I have tried scraping the whole of "subtext" and then taking the first element of the list but that didn't seem to work.

This is a sample of my code if you run this you will see that the first element of the output is what I after ("U", "AA")

```
import requests
from googlesearch import search 
import csv
import pandas
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import os

for film in ["return of the Jedi", "life of brian"]:
    query = film + " imdb"
    for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2):
        page = requests.get(j)
        response = page.status_code
        if response == 200:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
            filmData = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"subtext"})
            print(filmData)
```

I tried

```
print(filmData[0])
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you give some example URLs or the actual HTML?

Comment: You don't need the URL due to the code using googlesearch